# Slow script using API

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm writing a script that checks to see if an instagram user is followed by his followers or not. I have the list stored in a DB and for testing purposes I only have 20 user IDs in that list. The script is crazy slow. For the 35 people it takes ~12 seconds to load the page. Can anyone see why this basic script is so slow? Or is it just instagrams API?

NOTE: I've hidden the access token and my user id - not sure if it's good to have that public.

Code:

```
<?php

require_once 'instagram.class.php';


session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli("***","***","***","***");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
};


if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Jobs")) {
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            $group_arr[] = $obj;
        }; 
        $userid = $group_arr[0]->id;
        $token = $group_arr[0]->token;         
        $status = $group_arr[0]->status;
        $list = explode(",", $group_arr[0]->follower_list);
    $result->close();
};

echo "<pre>";
print_r($group_arr);
echo "</pre>";


// check authentication
if ($token === false) {
  // authentication failed - throw an error
  //error placeholder
} else {
$instagram->setAccessToken($token);


foreach($group_arr as $job) {
    if($status=="start"){
        foreach($list as $entry){
            $call = $instagram->getUserRelationship($entry)->data->outgoing_status;
            if($call == "follows"){
        echo "follows<br>";
            }else{
        echo "doesn't follow<br>";

            };
        };
    }else{
        //it's marked as stop, do nothing.
    };

};


};//close it out


?>
```

And this is the response:

> Array (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => ***
>               [token] => ***
>               [status] => start
>               [following_list] => 1161426957,191435508,1440954439,1463650509,1367056800,1446648791,1014674606,410710231,295958914,438752574,24520438,616513427,186915865,894461147,1395519590,256814697,1445364137,493354751,1455922632,1385122226,1161426957,191435508,1440954439,1463650509,1367056800,1446648791,1014674606,410710231,295958914,438752574,24520438,616513427,186915865,894461147,1395519590
>           )
>
> )
>
> doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow
>   doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't
>   follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow
>   doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't
>   follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow
>   doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't
>   follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow
>   doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow doesn't follow

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a curl_multi would speed this up. Can anyone verify this? I'm googling it and trying to learn about it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done `curl_multi` from the get go. that completely solved everything and the script runs so much faster. 
For anyone else browsing this, the instagram API is slow and shotty. the less calls you can make per interaction the better. If you have 100+ calls I'd recommend [curl_multi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the API.
Are you sure if the API is intended to be used on this way?

I recommend you do a benchmark for your calls to the Instagram API, so you can check how many seconds it takes.

so, you should add this code:

```
foreach($group_arr as $job) {
    if($status=="start"){
        foreach($list as $entry){
//MODIFY HERE---
            $start_time = microtime(true);
            $call = $instagram->getUserRelationship($entry)->data->outgoing_status;
            $end_time = microtime(true);
            echo "getUserRelationship for: ", $entry, " takes ", ($end_time - $start_time), "ms\n<br />\n";
//--------------
            if($call == "follows"){
        echo "follows<br>";
            }else{
        echo "doesn't follow<br>";

            };
        };
    }else{
        //it's marked as stop, do nothing.
    };

};
```

If you're having this problem on your dev environment, you can check how many time it takes on your production environment.

I hope this has been helpful for you.

Comment: there is a typo with your added code. `$star_time` on the echo should be `$start_time`. But yes, the API is supposed to be used in that manner as it even has it's own function to get the user status. The average call takes about .4ms